# UIButton touch is delayed when in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, touchescancelled

I'm running into a small issue in my app.

I essentially have a series of `UIButtons` added as subviews in a `UIScrollView` which is part of a nib. Every time I tap on a button there is a noticeable delay before the button is highlighted. I essentially have to hold it for about half a second before the button dims and appears selected.

I'm assuming this is because the `UIScrollView` needs to determine if the touch is a scroll or if it's a touch that is meant for a subview.

Anyways, I'm a little unsure on how to proceed. I simply want the button to appear selected as soon as I tap it.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

I've tried setting `delaysContentTouches` to *NO* but scrolling becomes almost impossible since a majority of my scrollView is filled with `UIButtons`.

Comment: Consider checking out this answer instead of the accepted one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19656611/378024

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok I've solved this by subclassing `UIScrollView` and overriding `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`

Now my `UIButton` that was tagged as 99 highlights properly and my scrollview is scrolling!

*myCustomScrollView.h*:

```
@interface myCustomScrollView : UIScrollView  {

}

@end
```

and *myCustomScrollView.m*:

```
@implementation myCustomScrollView

    - (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
    {
        NSLog(@"touchesShouldCancelInContentView");

        if (view.tag == 99)
            return NO;
        else 
            return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I just came across this answer and it completely solved the issue I was having. Wish I could give you +1000 points! Thank you so much.

Comment: doesn't work in my case, but it very close to your.(tested in simulator only). Maybe this solution time is up.

Answer (score 62):

Jeff's solution wasn't quite working for me, but this similar one does: http://charlesharley.com/2013/programming/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell-has-no-highlight-state

In addition to overriding `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` in your scroll view subclass, you still need to set `delaysContentTouches` to `false`. Lastly, you need to return `true` rather than `false` for your buttons. Here's a modified example from the above link. As commenters suggested, it checks for any subclass of `UIControl` rather than `UIButton` specifically so that this behavior applies to any type of control.

**Objective-C:**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.delaysContentTouches = false;
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:UIControl.class]) {
        return true;
    }

    return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view is UIControl {
        return true
    }
    return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
}
```

Comment: this works for me and not the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent solution! If you're using interface builder just select the scrollView and uncheck 'delays content touches' in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Tested all solutions posted here on iOS 8. Only this one prevents touch delays on buttons and doesn't interfere with scrolling.

Comment: **This is THE solution**. You can get springboard-like effect (touch animation starts early without any delay, but cancels if you still decide to scroll).

Comment: if view is UIControl is even better

Comment: You could probably check the `UIControl` instead of the `UIButton` to make sure your "Button" like subclasses of `UIControl` behave the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alexander and Jakub, I agree. I updated the examples accordingly.

Comment: for those of you who came here for an UICollectionViewController. You should make a UICollectionView subclass file and write the code in it.

Comment: Has anyone encountered the problem if a UIswitch is placed in a table? it seems that in this case the method is not called at all

Comment: delaysContentTouches is great and for some reason ChatGPT didn't know this. Hmmmm... nice!

Answer (score 30):

Try to set UIScrollView `delaysContentTouches` property to NO.

Comment: Sorry I probably should've been more clear. If I set delaysContentTouches to NO the touch responds immediately. However, scrolling pretty much becomes impossible since touches are interpreted as button presses rather than actual scrolling.

Comment: @Jeff You can use `canCancelContentTouches` to allow scrolling even if the touch is initially treated as a button touch, so long as the targets of the touch support cancellation. The buttons will still highlight initially when touched, but as soon as you start to scroll will unhighlight.

Comment: @chaiguy I am looking for this behaviour, exactly like you described, but no luck so far. If I set `delaysContentTouches = NO` and `canCancelContentTouches = YES` I am not able to scroll when touching UIButton at all.

Comment: @Darrarski Sorry I was thinking of a `UITableViewCell` not a `UIButton`. It appears the button doesn't support cancelled touches because it allows you to drag off the button to cancel it, overriding the scroll view ever receiving the drag. I'm not sure how to achieve this with a `UIButton`, but you could probably do it by subclassing `UIButton`.

Answer (score 3):

Storyboard solution: Select the scroll view, open the "Attributes Inspector" and uncheck "Delays Content Touches"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 :

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Comment: worked for me in CollectionView. Swift 5.5

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

class ScrollViewWithButtons: UIScrollView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        myInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        myInit()
    }

    private func myInit() {
        self.delaysContentTouches = false
    }

    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if view is UIButton {
            return true
        }
        return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
    }
}
```

You can then use this `ScrollViewWithButtons` in IB or in code.

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing solutions worked for me. Maybe my situation is more unique.

I have many `UIButtons` within a `UIScrollView`. When a `UIButton` is pressed a new `UIViewController` is presented to the user. If a button is pressed and held long enough, the button will show its depressed state. My client was complaining that if you tap too quickly, no depressed state is shown.

My solution:
Inside the `UIButtons`' tap method, where I load the new `UIViewController` and present it on screen, I use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadNextScreenWithOptions:) 
           withObject:options 
           afterDelay:0.]
```

This schedules the loading of the next `UIViewController` on the next event loop. Allowing time for the `UIButton` to redraw. The `UIButton` now shows its depressed state before loading the next `UIViewController`.