# Delay of button's highlighted state

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7

I have the issue in two completely different situations, which makes it really weird.

1. Situation: A UIButton in as a subView of another UIView.
2. Situation: UIBarButtonItem's in a UIToolBar.

In both situations the buttons's are only highlighted after a slight delay, approximately .5 - 1 second. Definitely to long to highlight the view when tapping it normally. They both work perfectly on the simulator, but not on a real device (I have an iPhone 5s with iOS 7.0.4).

**What I tried** 
Setting the zPosition to the highest value (MAXFLOAT) of these views, to ensure nothing is blocking the tap. 
Explicitly enabling the highlighting.

Both obviously doesn't worked.

Edit: Still not solved.

Comment: Aren´t you doing something like server calls on main thread when tapping those buttons? That could cause a delay in the highlight. You should make those calls in background if yes.

Comment: is highlight an image in png format ?

Comment: I guess you are doing some heavy work when tapping those buttons. Image rendering is working on main thread. You may check IBAction funtion for the buttons.

Comment: I do nothing in the actions of the buttons, except logging that it has been tapped.

Answer (score 8):

This can happen if the buttons are placed close to the bottom edge of the display. There's a conflict with the system edge gesture to present Control Center (or App Switcher on iPhone X and iPad). It delays touches for your buttons until it's determined the user isn't performing a system gesture.

If you would like, you can tell the system to give precedence to your gestures over the system gestures.

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return .bottom
}
```

Do note however that this will require the user swipe twice to activate the system gesture.

Comment: or in Objective-C : `-(UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
{
    return UIRectEdgeBottom;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Are the UIButtons inside a UIScrollView ?
If they are, the delay is there so the scrollview can determine whether the touch is for scrolling or it should be passed on to the subview.

See also [UIButton touch is delayed when in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642547/uibutton-touch-is-delayed-when-in-uiscrollview)

Comment: No. Also: I made sure there weren't and was completely aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time, but I just faced a similar issue:

- My `UIButton` is a subview of `UINavigationController.view`
- There's no delay on the simulator
- But there's a delay to show the highlight on the device

I just found out that it only happens if I run the app from Xcode. If I disconnect the device and open the app from it's icon everything works just fine.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I can confirm I'm seeing this behavior as of Xcode 9.4. Great catch!