# UICollectionView mysteriously delaying touches until scrolled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have the strangest bug where cells in a `UICollectionView` have started behaving erratically. I tap a cell and it is selected (with a custom animation that brings it into a full screen state) but then when I try to tap a button contained in that subview it does not respond. However, as soon as I scroll the view, it registers the missing taps.

The effect is deferring events including both `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath` and  button actions wired up in Interface Builder.

I'm not sure what questions I should be asking here - any advice?

Comment: If _"full screen state"_ view is a `UIScrollView` try `fullScreenView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`. Also look through [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642547/uibutton-touch-is-delayed-when-in-uiscrollview) for possible workarounds (if it is a scrollview)

Comment: That's interesting - if I uncheck the collection view's Scroll View "Delays Content Touches" I always get this effect, so that's the right area... I'll read up on what that actually does...

Answer (score 1):

I had a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` registered on the cell within the scroll view that was deferring all the events until the scroll view scrolled.