# UITableView Add FooterView Button Sometimes Tap Doesn't Perform Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a simple UITableView that I've added a UIButton to the Footer.

Similar to this:

```
self.btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.btn.backgroundColor = darkPurple;
[self.btn setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.btn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100); 
self.btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.btn;
```

Sometimes when I get scrolled to the bottom of the TableView if it isn't completely settled the Button won't perform the action. Sometimes it will flash (`showsTouchWhenHighlighted`) but I'll need to tap it again.

What am I missing here? I've tried solutions like this but it doesn't appear to work.

[UIButton touch is delayed when in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642547/uibutton-touch-is-delayed-when-in-uiscrollview)

I want to it process always, even if the scroll isn't settled and not delay.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

Nothing. That's just how touches work on iOS. You can see the same thing in Mobile Safari: if the page is still scrolling, tapping a link doesn't work. You have to wait until the page is completely stopped ("settled", as you rightly say).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there is no way to disable this? It's annoying to have the button "flash" and then have nothing happen.

Comment: I agree. I think that happens because the button "eats the touch" while the scroll animation is going on. (That phrase comes from an Apple WWDC video from some years ago.) You _might_ be able to work around this by putting a UITapGestureRecognizer on the button. Be careful because you then have to mediate between whether it is the button itself or the gesture recognizer that is responding.

Comment: Matt, can you explain? I've added a UITapGestureRecognizer instead and its performing the exact same way. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't say the tap gesture recognizer trick would work, I said it _might_ work. I've never tried it.